# Display Order number in Paypal

Tags: php, paypal

I am using standard Paypal method for multiple product. I want to display the order number in the Paypal widget for each transaction. This order number is must be visible for buyers in the Paypal widget.Can anyone say how to display the order number to the buyers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach a custom field and pass the order number.

'&lt input type="hidden" name="custom" value="#your order number#" &gt'

Comment: Thanks for your replu. But I have tried this one. It's not displaying the value in the Paypal. It just returning the value to notify_url page

Comment: The custom flag value will appear as soon as you are redirected to paypal, you can cross check this field in the transaction list.

Comment: You should see the value in the transaction details in the sellers account.  It will not show in the buyers account though.